# How do I create multiple locations with Nginx, Passenger, Sinatra

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra, passenger, rack

I have a server section that looks like:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  arch;
    root   /data/apps/production/fentonGem2/current/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

which works fine.  However, I'd like to deploy two or more apps to the same `server_name` and `listen` port.  So presumably I'd use something like the following:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  arch;
    location /app1 {
         root   /data/apps/production/fentonGem2/current/public;
         passenger_enabled on;
    }
    location /app2 {
         root   /data/apps/production/fentonGem3/current/public;
         passenger_enabled on
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work. Does anyone know how I can deploy two separate apps, and reach them by:

```
http://domain.com/app1/
```

and:

```
http://domain.com/app2/
```

The setup uses Nginx, Phusion Passenger, Rack, and Sinatra.

---

UPDATE:

Thanks for the responses, but I found them and the approach not helpful, though maybe I'm not understanding it well.  It kind of seems like I have to deploy one application inside another, which seems very unclean.  What I finally resorted to was having separate `server` sections, and then updating my `/etc/hosts` file to have server aliases for the same IP address.  So now I have:

```
http://app1/
```

and:

```
http://app2/
```

and server sections that look like:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  app1;
    root /data/apps/production/app1/current/public;        
    passenger_enabled on;        
}               
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app2;
    root /data/apps/production/app2/current/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

and in /etc/hosts:

```
192.168.1.30     app1 app2
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but you might need `passenger_base_uri /app1;`

More about Passenger and Nginx conf:
http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerBaseURI

EDIT:

> "It is allowed to specify this option multiple times. Do this to deploy multiple applications in different sub-URIs under the same virtual host."

Answer (score 1):

The following worked:

1. First made symlinks named `app1` and `app2` pointing to the "public" directory as follows:

   ```
   ln -s /data/apps/production/fentonGem2/current/public /data/apps/production/fentonGem2/current/app1
   ln -s /data/apps/production/fentonGem2/current/public /data/apps/production/fentonGem2/current/app2
   ```
2. Modify nginx.conf to have `rails_base_uri`, which should look something like the following:

   ```
   ...
   server {
       listen       80;
       server_name  arch;
       location ^~ /app1 {
           root /data/apps/production/fentonGem2/current;
           rails_env production;
           passenger_enabled on;
           passenger_base_uri /app1;
       }
       location ^~ /app2 {
           root /data/apps/production/fentonGem2/current;
           rails_env production;
           passenger_enabled on;
           passenger_base_uri /app2;
       }
   } 
   ...
   ```

Hope this helps.